# How to put script into elasticsearch using their node client?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using the latest version of **elasticsearch** [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) with **elasticsearch** version **6.4** and trying to put new `script`.

According to thier [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/16.x/api-reference-6-8.html#api-putscript-6-8); `putScript` function takes `id` and `body` properties.

So when i try to call it, for instance:

```
client.putScript({
    id: 'date_formatter',
    body: {
        lang: "painless",
        source: `// Get each field value as string
            String datetime = doc[params.field].value.toString();
            // Create format object based on string
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(params.format);
            // cast datetime into ZonedDateTime to use format function
            ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime);
            // return formatted date
            return zdt.format(formatter);`
    }
})
```

It returns `{ acknowledged: true }` as expected, But when i check it through **kibana**, it returns:

```
{
  "_id": "date_formatter",
  "found": true,
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": """{"lang":"painless"}"""
  }
}
```

Is there any way to put `script` into **elasticsearch** through node client?

Comment: There's a typo `land` should read `lang`

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap both `lang` and `source` into a `script` section basically the same way [as described here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#modules-scripting-stored-scripts):

```
client.putScript({
    id: 'date_formatter',
    body: {
        script: {
            lang: "painless",
            source: `// Get each field value as string
                String datetime = doc[params.field].value.toString();
                // Create format object based on string
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(params.format);
                // cast datetime into ZonedDateTime to use format function
                ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(datetime);
                // return formatted date
                return zdt.format(formatter);`
            }
        }
    })
```